# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, array, data-push

When pushing an array's contents i get
[image]

here is my code
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the context of `this` has changed within your each. Try this:

```
const self = this;

$.each(res, function(index, value) {
    self.qtyOptions.push(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Help it's working for me